# Parent Child ValidationRule

Tags: wpf, validationrule

I have a complicated scenario using ValidationRules that I need some help with.  I have a User Control that is roughly organized like this:

```
Parent (ItemsControl)
    Child 1
        Property 1
        Property 2
    Child 2
        Property 1
        Property 2
```

When Child 1.Property 1 is changed, I need to perform validation on it.  However, the validation rule requires the value of Child 1.Property 1 as well as the Property 1 values for all its siblings (variable number) to perform the validation.  I could put a  ValidationRule on the Parent ItemsControl, but I need the Control bound to Child1.Property1 to show the error.  Currently when I place the validation on the parent the error is displayed on the parent, not the child.  I've also considered using BindingGroups but I want the validation to fire automatically when a property is changed.  There isn't, to my knowledge, a way to automatically force Validation to fire for a BindingGroup.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: The validation is at the object level.  What I do is the ctor pass the collection to all the members so the member can walk the collection.

Answer (score 0):

This automatically turns all the object's data annotation attributes into `ValidationRule`s, and can be applied once in the app on all `TextBox`es:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

using DaValidationResult = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult;
using WinValidationResult = System.Windows.Controls.ValidationResult;

public sealed class DataAnnotationsBehavior
{
  public static bool GetValidateDataAnnotations(DependencyObject obj) =>
    (bool)obj.GetValue(ValidateDataAnnotationsProperty);
  public static void SetValidateDataAnnotations(DependencyObject obj, bool value) =>
    obj.SetValue(ValidateDataAnnotationsProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidateDataAnnotationsProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ValidateDataAnnotations", typeof(bool), 
        typeof(DataAnnotationsBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnPropertyChanged));

  private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var boolean = (bool)e.NewValue;
    if (!(d is TextBox textBox))
      throw new NotSupportedException(
        @$"The behavior " +
        "'{typeof(DataAnnotationsBehavior)}' can only be applied " +
        "on elements of type '{typeof(TextBox)}'.");

    var bindingExpression =
      textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

    if (boolean)
    {
      var dataItem = bindingExpression.DataItem;
      if (bindingExpression.DataItem == null)
        return;

      var type = dataItem.GetType();
      var prop = type.GetProperty(bindingExpression.ResolvedSourcePropertyName);
      if (prop == null)
        return;

      var allAttributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true);
      foreach (var validationAttr in allAttributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>())
      {
        var context = new ValidationContext(dataItem, null, null) 
        { MemberName = bindingExpression.ResolvedSourcePropertyName };

        bindingExpression
          .ParentBinding
          .ValidationRules
          .Add(new AttributesValidationRule(context, validationAttr));
      }
    }
    else
    {
      var das =
        bindingExpression
          .ParentBinding
          .ValidationRules
          .OfType<AttributesValidationRule>()
          .ToList();

      if (das != null)
        foreach (var da in das)
          bindingExpression.ParentBinding.ValidationRules.Remove(da);
    }
  }

  abstract class DaValidationRule : ValidationRule
  {
    public ValidationContext ValidationContext { get; }

    public DaValidationRule(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      ValidationContext = validationContext;
    }
  }

  class AttributesValidationRule : DaValidationRule
  {
    public ValidationAttribute ValidationAttribute { get; }

    public AttributesValidationRule(ValidationContext validationContext, 
      ValidationAttribute attribute)
      : base(validationContext) =>
      ValidationAttribute = attribute;

    public override WinValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
      var result = ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(value, ValidationContext);

      return result == DaValidationResult.Success
        ? WinValidationResult.ValidResult
        : new WinValidationResult(false, result.ErrorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter 
        Property="local:DataAnnotationsBehavior.ValidateDataAnnotations" 
        Value="True"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
          <Setter 
            Property="ToolTip" 
            Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Model}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I made the `DaValidationRule` class abstract because I think I might want to expand that in the future so it also covers `IValidationAttribute` and maybe other scenarios.

For the version that covers `TextBox`es within `DataGridTextColumn` in edit mode, and for **full code**, see [this](https://gist.github.com/weitzhandler/5a2d39df8ddc31fca23a1d097fa2d6bc).