# What is the difference between ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors and ValidatesOnDataErrors and NotifyOnValidationError in WPF validation?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml

In **WPF validation**, whats the difference between the following:

> ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors = True
>
> ValidatesOnDataErrors = True
>
> NotifyOnValidationError = True

When should you use these properties correctly in XAML?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors` and `ValidatesOnDataErrors` are used when you want a XAML bound control to validate its input based on an interface implemented in the ViewModel/Model, for `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors` that interface is [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and for `ValidatesOnDataErrors` it is [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
for example let's say you have a view model like this:

```cs
class PersonViewModel : IDataErrorInfo {

    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error 
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName] {
        if (columnName == "FirstName" &&) {
            if (this.FirstName.Length > 20)
                return "FirstName can't be more than 20 characters.";

        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

}
```

and then in your view you have a textbox that is bound to the FirstName property like this:
`<TextBox Text={Binding Path=FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True} />`
now if the user entered 20 characters or more in the textbox an error will be detected.

On the other hand `NotifyOnValidationError` is used when you want an event to be raised when the bound fails validation.

<del>I usually use `ValidatesOnDataErrors` in my XAML controls for validation and i haven't had a need for the other two, so it depends on your situation.</del>

**EDIT:** I am updating my answer as I have learned some new things, so I need to make this more relevant.

`ValidatesOnDataErrors` is used in thick clients, or in other words when the validation is performed on the client side such as a desktop WPF or WinForm application and model objects implement `IDataErrorInfo`.

On the other hand, `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors` would be a better fit for thin clients *(multi-tier applications)* such as client-server applications *(Silverlight, WPF with WCF, etc ..)* where the validation takes place on the server.

This way when the user types something for example in a TextBox, the value is sent to the server asynchronously for validation, and when validation results come back an event is raised *([ErrorsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.errorschanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event to be exact)*, then the view picks that up and displays it using the appropriate method, of course in this case the model would implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: Another thing to note ... is that INotifyDataErrorInfo is only available in .NET 4.5 and forward ... and if you are stuck supporting Windows XP (and therefore you can't use .NET 4.5), then you are stuck with IDataErrorInfo instead of INotifyDataErrorInfo.

Comment: Can I have the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` implemented in the VM whilst the model is a POCO provided via a property on the VM?

Comment: Hi @Shimmy, I honestly haven't worked with anything WPF for several years now so cannot really help you.

Comment: Thanks. I came up with a different solution, posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59203094/75500) for the reference.

Answer (score 8):

Just for your info: `IDataErrorInfo.Error` is not used in WPF and can return null or throw a `NotImplementedException`.
This property was used in WinForms.

Personally, I prefer to use `INotifyDataErrorInfo` because it allows to have multiple error messages mapped to a single property.

Comment: it seems to show errors in real time when idataerrorinfo wait you lose focus on the control you want to test.

Comment: @Vonkel. To trigger the validation, the source must be updated. Therefore the time of the validation occurring depends on the current value of UpdateSourceTrigger property. So setting it to PropertyChanged makes the validation fire immediately after any change to the bound property.