# Required Data Annotation not working using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im using WPF/XAML (first time coding using this technology) and Im trying to send an error message when the user did not selected any of the options inside a combobox.

This is the code so far:

In my backend im using an entity like so:

```
public class Scanner : ValidationBase
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    //[Range(1, int.MaxValue,ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Scanner), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ScannerConfigurationInfo_Required")]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ScannerConfigurationInfo_Required")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }
}
```

And this is my ViewModel (for simplicity I took part of the code that does not impact on this question):

```
 class ScannerSettingsViewModel : ModalViewModelBase, IScannerSettingsViewModel
    {
        private const string SCANNER_ID = "ScannerId";
        private ObservableCollection<Scanner> _availableScanners;
        private Scanner _scannerSelected;

        public AwaitableDelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
        public AwaitableDelegateCommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ScannerConfigurationInfo_Required")]
        public Scanner ScannerSelected
        {
            get { return _scannerSelected; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _scannerSelected, value); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Scanner> AvailableScanners
        {
            get { return _availableScanners; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _availableScanners, value); }
        }

        //Services
        private readonly INavigationService _navigation;
        private readonly ICheckDirectService _checkDirectService;
        private readonly ISession _session;

        public ScannerSettingsViewModel(INavigationService navigation, ISession session, 
            ICheckDirectService checkDirectService) 
        {
            _navigation = navigation;
            _session = session;
            _checkDirectService = checkDirectService;


            SaveCommand = new AwaitableDelegateCommand(SaveCommand_Execute);
            CancelCommand = new AwaitableDelegateCommand(CancelCommand_Execute);
        }


        private async Task SaveCommand_Execute()
        {
            await ScannerSelected.FireValidation();

            if (ScannerSelected.HasErrors)
            {
                return;
            }

            _session.Computer.Settings[SCANNER_ID] = ScannerSelected.Id.ToString();

            await _session.Computer.Settings.SaveChanges();

            await CloseDialog();
        }
    }
```

And this is my XAML (again, for simplicity sake I took only the part that corresponds with the question):

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Row ="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableScanners}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding ScannerConfigurationInfo.ScannerSetting, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding ScannerConfigurationInfo.ScannerSetting.Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              Margin="20 50 20 50"  
              md:HintAssist.Hint="{l:LocText ScannerConfiguration_Model}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="Name"
              Style="{DynamicResource ComboboxDynamic}">
    </ComboBox>
```

So, the combobox will not have any option selected as default (this is intended) and the idea is that, there is a save button that fires the `SaveCommand_Execute` method, it DOES bring the error in the `.HasErrors`, but doesn't "paint it" on the front end.

Comment: This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254847/what-is-the-difference-between-validatesonnotifydataerrors-and-validatesondataer) point to implementing a specific interface named `IDataErrorInfo`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on my `ComboBox` in `SelectedValue`, `SelectedItem`. Those were pointing to another property instead of `SelectedScanner` and on `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` were pointing on `Name` instead of `Id`